# Only Switch.setChecked doesn't work when fragment is shown?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    private FragmentA a;
    private FragmentB b;
    private FragmentC c;
    private HomeFragment mHomeFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity_layout);
     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mHomeFragment) // replace flContainer
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

    ...
    }
```

I use some lazy initializer, and I keep my object a, b, c and mHomeFragment inside my activity object,

I have a button inside 'b' that calls the MainActivity to call 'c'
and a button inside 'c' that calls the MainActivity to call 'b'

and some other buttons to call 'a' which is not that important

Well now inside my FragmentB I have some custom views,

```
  public CustomView(Context cnx, SettingsViewElement e, FragmentA fragment)
    {
    super(cnx);
    inflate(cnx, R.layout.my_layout,this);
    parent = fragment; // I use it later in my onCheckedChangeListener to tell him the the switch has been checked 
    condition = parent.getCondition();

    titleTv = this.findViewById(R.id.title_tv);
    switch  = this.findViewById(R.id.switch);
    if(condition){
    switch.setChecked(true);
    titleTv.setTitle("i am depressed af :(");

    }
```

my question is :

**why my switch doesn't turn checked even if my titleTv is updating the title ??**

I did some tests and my OnCreated() is called each time I call replace() in my fragment transaction.

my fragment re-instantiate the views and then will add them to a linearLayout after inflating layout.

**Also, if I don't keep my fragments reference in my MainActivity and then re-instantiate it every time.
here : the switch.setChecked will  work** ,
but the backStack will be huge and dumb

example: stack = 'b' -> 'c' -> 'b' -> 'c'
normally when the user click twice return button he'll be back to homeFragment, it doesn't need to empty the stack by itself.

and even if I override @onBackPressed() and re-instantiate the fragments each time hoping the android sdk will free the space.

I will have to do it manually each time I want to add a new fragment in my design, it will be a a wheel re-invention.

and : ***IT DOES NOT EXPLAIN WHY*** THE Switch.setChecked() doesn't work even if the condition is true and the other views are updating (textView is updating it's text)

> Update : Apparently,
>
> if the fragment is being re-used and the onCreate() is called for the
> second time, (the reference for the fragment is being kept somewhere
> and fragment is being attached for a second time) here the setChecked
> will not take an effect, only some other view updates
>
> meanwhile, it will only work if it's being called for the first time
> the fragment is being created,
>
> Solution : updating the views in the OnResume() method
>
> If someone has an explanation for this, please go ahead

Answer (score 0):

Views save and restore (some) of there state in the course of saveInstanceState/restoreInstance cycle, but unfortunatrly the checked state (and also visibility etc) are not covered by that.
So you'll have implement onSaveInstanceState etc. for your fragment and save/restore the checked state yourself.

**EDIT**

From your question it is not apparent what view `switch` actually is so I cannot give you actual code. But have a look at the implementation of [CheckedTextView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java) and check out the implementation of `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. You'll see that they save and restore the checked state (it's quite a lot of code with the SavedState class but in the end it is pretty simple). What you need to do, is to implement those two methods for your custom view (also creating your own SavedState inner class) and save/restore the checked state of your switch view.

A completely different and better approach would be to use a *ViewModel* for your fragment that holds the state, but that's a different story that would require lots of changes to your complete implementation.

Comment: I don't get it please explain more, 
the checked state if fact isn't stored in the fragment , 

my view on the creation calles the fragment parent, who will call the activity to get the state condition (whether it should be activated or not). 

so, i am not counting on the view itself to store the checked status, i am just trying to call setChecked(true); and make it work when creating the view 


 setChecked(true) isn't working even if i'm 100% that it was executed

Answer (score 0):

Update : 
Apparently,

if the fragment is being re-used and the onCreate() is called for the seconde time, (the reference for the fragment is being kept somewhere and fragment is being attached for a seconde time)
**here the setChecked will not take an effect, only some other view updates**

meanwhile, it will only work if it's being called for the first time the fragment is being created,

Solution : 
**updating the views in the OnResume() methode**

If someone has an explanation for this, 
please go ahead

Comment: What do you mean by: "updating the views in the OnResume() method". Could you please explain that?